# How to resample data inside multiindex dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, resampling

I have the following dataframe:[image]

I need to resample the data to calculate the weekly pct_change(). How can i get the weekly change ?

Something like `data['pct_week'] = data['Adj Close'].resample('W').ffill().pct_change()` but the data need to groupby `data.groupby(['month', 'week'])`

This way every month would yield 4 values for weekly change.Which i can graph then

What i did was `df['pct_week'] = data['Adj Close'].groupby(['week', 'day']).pct_change()` but i got this error `TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 5):

If want grouping with resample first is necessary `DatetimeIndex` only, so added 
[`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) by all levels without first, then grouping and resample with custom function, because `pct_change` for `resample` is not implemented:

```
def percent_change(x):
    return pd.Series(x).pct_change()
```

Another idea is use numpy solution for `pct_change`:

```
def percent_change(x):
    return x / np.concatenate(([np.nan], x[:-1])) - 1
```

---

```
df1 = (df.reset_index(level=[1,2,3])
        .groupby(['month', 'week'])['Adj Close']
        .resample('W')
        .apply(percent_change))
```

---

> this way every month would yield 4 values for weekly change

So it seems there is no `groupby`, only necessary downsample like `sum` and chain [`Series.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html):

```
df2 = (df.reset_index(level=[1,2,3])
        .resample('W')['Adj Close']
        .sum()
        .pct_change())
```

Answer (score 4):

Drop unwanted indexes. The datetime index is enough for re-sampling / grouping

```
df.index = df.index.droplevel(['month', 'week', 'day'])
```

Re-sample by week, select the column needed, add a aggregation function and then calculate percentage change.

```
df.resample('W')['Adj Close'].mean().pct_change()
```